# Sending cookies in a SOAP request using Suds

Tags: python, soap, cookies, suds

I'm trying to access a SOAP API using Suds. The SOAP API documentation states that I have to provide three cookies with some login data. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a "Cookie" HTTP Request Header having the required name/value pairs. This is how Cookie values are usually transmitted in HTTP Based systems. You can add multiple key/value pairs in the same http header.

**Single Cookie**

> Cookie: name1=value1

**Multiple Cookies** (seperated by semicolons)

> Cookie: name1=value1; name2=value2